# How to close v-select on click outside v-app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an vue app that user vuetify. The app is used inside existing cms.
When a dropdown select is opened a click outside the app does not close the dropdown. If the click is inside the app region, the dropdown closes.

Any idea how can I trigger close for the opened dropdown on click outside the app ?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#cartbutton',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{text:'a'}, {text:'b'}]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.existing-cms {
  padding: 40px 50px;
}

#app {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel=stylesheet>

<div class="existing-cms">
  <p>Click on the select dropdown and leave it open.</p>
  <p>
    Click on this white region outside the app should somehow close
    opened select in the app.
  </p>
  
  <div id="cartbutton">
    <v-app>
      <span>Clicking here insde the app closed the opened select</span>
      <br><br>
      <v-select label="Click me and leave it opened. Then click in the white region." :items="items"></v-select>
    </v-app>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Here is a codepen link https://codepen.io/darkopetreski/pen/OGMvop

EDIT:

It seems that this is reported as a bug here https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3144 and the suggestion is to use data-app="true" at the root element, but this approach is not good, since it will mess up stuff (at least was not working well for me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a rather hacky solution but it seems to work. There are two changes:

1) Add a window click listener that calls the blur method on the v-select. This hides the control. To facilitate this I added a ref to the v-select component.

2) To prevent this firing when they click inside the app or on the v-select, I added a stop propagation @click.stop onto the container.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeoOMz

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#cartbutton',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{text:'a'}, {text:'b'}]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("click",() => {
       this.$refs.select.blur();
    });    
  }
})
```

```css
.existing-cms {
  padding: 40px 50px;
}

#app {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel=stylesheet>

<div class="existing-cms">
  <p>Click on the select dropdown and leave it open.</p>
  <p>
    Click on this white region outside the app should somehow close
    opened select in the app.
  </p>
  
  <div id="cartbutton" @click.stop>
    <v-app>
      <span>Clicking here insde the app closed the opened select</span>
      <br><br>
      <v-select ref="select" label="Click me and leave it opened. Then click in the white region." :items="items"></v-select>
    </v-app>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I found another approach, to add data-app="true" to the body element of the cms as I edited the question, but this approach messes some stuff to my cms. So for now the safest way is as your approach to add event listener.

Comment: @jcbdrn  is this still working? for my scenario, blur not working?